# How to know the video size before export -- After Effects

Tags: after-effects

Could I know the video size before I export it?

After I set the settings, before render it, can I know the video size?

[image]

Comment: This question would get better answers on videoproduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the video is set in the settings of the composition. In the render module of your render queue item it the size of the comp can be changed by the resolution. In the output module you also have the possibility of resizing the result or cropping it.

With your composition active you use Menu>Composition>Composition Settings to see the current settings of the comp.

Comment: I don't know if you misunderstand my intend, I want to know if I can know the video size before render it.

Comment: you mean an estimated file size?

Comment: I think if you use the media encoder you'll get an estimate